# Replacement of json url with php url not working

Tags: php, android, json, listview, android-volley

I am working on android app in which a listview with some text retrieve from server The source is here [source link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/). This is my php code

```
<?php
require_once("dbConnect.php");
$sql = "SELECT image,fullname,location from uploadfinding";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result, array(
            "image"=>$row[0],
            "fullname"=>$row[1],
            "location"=>$row[2]));
           echo " over";
            }
        echo json_encode($result);
      mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and this is my json response

```
 Connected successfully over over over[{"image":myurl\/uploadfinding\/uploads\/2016-04-25 06:38:051461584281226.jpg","fullname":"adi","location":"fgh"},{"image":myurl\/uploadfinding\/uploads\/2016-04-25 06:38:201461584297706.jpg","fullname":"adi2","location":"fgh2"},{"image":myurl\/uploadfinding\/uploads\/2016-04-25 06:45:441461584739479.jpg","fullname":"adi23","location":"cn"}]
```

I have lots of things tried but result is none.the complete source is here:

I am not posting here any java file bacause this example is worked fine for this url:

```
http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json
```

But when i replace this with my url:

```
http://myurl/PhotoUpload/getAllImages.php
```

It return only empty activity.

Comment: Change 'myurl' with your Server Url where you placed php file.

Comment: Dear my url is not matter...

Comment: Hi did u check whether the data is coming into the array `$result` ?

Comment: I m not getting ur point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php
    header("content-type:application/json");
    require_once("dbConnect.php");

    $sql = "SELECT x1,x2,x3 from table_name";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            array_push($result, array(

                "x1"=>$row["x1"],
                "x2"=>$row['x2'],
                "x3"=>$row["x3"]));

                echo " over";
            }


    echo json_encode($result);
    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($result));
fclose($fp);

    mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
```

replace your url "http://myurl/PhotoUpload/getAllImages.php"  with "http://myurl/PhotoUpload/results.json"

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: 
from within your app, you can simply refer to the emulator as

> 'localhost' or 127.0.0.1.

or

If you are running with real device means pass correct url like

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/android/php_server/register.php

Edit:

Try compare your url,

> myurl/uploadfinding/uploads/2016-04-25 06:38:051461584281226.jpg"

with

> "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg" this.

At your response, **"** double quote is missing at front of image tag

pass image link like,

> "your_link"

Comment: i think response is not ok. check my updated answer.